# RegEx in Shell script concatenates RegEx filter into filename

Tags: bash, shell, logic, glob

I want to detect if a file with a certain datestamp in the name is in a directory. However there is also a timestamp concatenated to it. I can calculate the datestamp but not the timestamp so i need some kind of a wildcard.

This is the example filename:
`backup_myserver_202310152100.log`
This is my expression:
`log_file="backup_${hostname_arg}_${logfile_sunday}[0-9]*.log"`
but it searches actually for this filename (checked by echo):
`backup_myserver_20231015[0-9]*.log`

The timestamp is always represented by for digits if it helps.

I tried to get the solution from the www and other questions here but it seems i'm just not made for RegEx.

I tried the expression above as well the following:
`log_file="backup_${hostname_arg}_${logfile_sunday}{....}.log"`
since i read the one point does represent one character. Sources are very divers in answers.

Comment: Regex solution looks simpler `backup_myserver_20231015\d{4}\.log`. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning the variable it is the pattern itself (`backup_myserver_20231015[0-9]*.log`) that is stored in your variable, not its expansion to existing file names, because 1) you double-quoted it (pathname expansion is not done between quotes) and 2) pathname expansion is never done in the right hand side of parameter assignments.

A simple way to verify all this is to type `declare -p log_file` to see what `log_file` is and what value it has. You can also type `echo "$log_file"` which prints the pattern and `echo $log_file` which prints the file names if they exist because `$log_file` is not quoted and the pathname expansion is performed before `echo` is executed.

A better way is to assign an array, with the unquoted pattern, and the `nullglob` option on, such that the pattern expands as the empty string if there are no matching logfiles (output prefixed with `-|` ):

```
shopt -s nullglob
log_file=( backup_${hostname_arg}_${logfile_sunday}[0-9]*.log )
if (( ${#log_file[@]} == 0 )); then
  printf 'no log files\n'
else
  printf '%s\n' "${log_file[@]}"
fi
-| backup_myserver_202310152100.log
-| backup_myserver_202310152101.log
...
```

And if you want to match exactly 4 digits you can try:

```
$ log_file=( backup_${hostname_arg}_${logfile_sunday}[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9].log )
```

You could also use the `find` from GNU `findutils`, if you have that, with regular expressions instead of the simpler glob patterns:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype gnu-awk -type f -regex "\./backup_${hostname_arg}_${logfile_sunday}[0-9]{4}\.log"
```

Comment: Thanks this is it. My mistake was not the regex itself but the way i used it. Thanks for the explanation of my false handling

Answer (score 1):

Your command seems to work fine

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name  "backup_myserver_[0-9]*.log"
```

I tried to put this in a small shell script as well and it worked there as well

```bash
#!/bin/bash
expr='backup_myserver_[0-9]*.log'
result=$(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${expr}")
echo $result
```

[Code result of shell script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OTKc.png)